# C pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

I made this BinaryTree implementation, which works fine except for the freeTree() method that says I am trying to free a pointer that wasn't allocated. I just cannot find where my logic is wrong here.
I have no idea how to find exactly the pointer it at.
Any tips, tricks?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct BinaryTree
{
    int data;
struct BinaryTree *left;
struct BinaryTree *right;
};

typedef struct BinaryTree BinaryTree;

FILE *input;
FILE *output;

char dat[99];
int number;

BinaryTree tree;

void add(int data, BinaryTree *tree);
void inorderTraversal(BinaryTree *tree);
void freeTree(BinaryTree *tree);

int main()
{
input = fopen("/Users/sergeymikhaylyuk/Desktop/Program/Tree/input.txt", "r");
output = fopen("/Users/sergeymikhaylyuk/Desktop/Program/Tree/sorted.txt", "w");
while (fgets(dat, sizeof(dat), input))
{
    sscanf(dat, "%i", &number);
    add(number, &tree);
}
inorderTraversal(&tree);
freeTree(&tree);

}

void add(int data, BinaryTree *tree)
{
if (tree->data == 0)
{
    tree->data = data;
}
else
{
    if (tree->data < data && tree->right != NULL)
    {
        add(data, tree->right);
    }
    else if (tree->data < data)
    {
        tree->right = malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
        add(data, tree->right);
    }
    else if (tree->data > data && tree->left != NULL)
    {
        add(data, tree->left);
    }
    else if (tree->data > data)
    {
        tree->left = malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
        add(data, tree->left);
    }
}
}

void inorderTraversal(BinaryTree *tree)
{
if (tree != NULL)
{
    if (tree->left != NULL)
    {
        inorderTraversal(tree->left);
    }
    fprintf(output, "%i ", tree->data);
    if (tree->right != NULL)
    {
        inorderTraversal(tree->right);
    }
}

}
int i = 1;
void freeTree(BinaryTree *tree)
{
printf("%i ", i);
i++;
if (tree != NULL)
{
    if (tree->left != NULL)
    {
        freeTree(tree->left);
    }
    if (tree->right != NULL)
    {
        freeTree(tree->right);
    }
    free(tree);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The root node is on the stack because of this line

```
BinaryTree tree;
```

All other nodes are on the heap.

But you `freeTree` function free's all nodes including the root. Hence it gives the error `trying to free a pointer which hasn't been malloced error`.

The simplest fix is to change the above to

```
BinaryTree * ptree = malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
ptree->data = 0;
ptree->left = NULL;
ptree->right = NULL;
```

and change all places where you are using `&tree` to `ptree`.

For eg.

```
add(number, &tree);
```

to

```
add(number, ptree);
```

Other than this, you also need to init left & right to NULL after you `malloc` at all places.

For eg. after

```
tree->right = malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
```

add

```
tree->right->data = 0;
tree->right->left = NULL;
tree->right->right = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate your nodes, you never initialize them before using them. The item returned by `malloc()` is ***not guaranteed*** to be initialized to zeros (or any other particular value). So you're `left` and `right` link pointers likely have garbage values. You should do something like this:

```
BinaryTree* alloc_node(void)
{
    BinaryTree* p = malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
    if (p) {
        p->data = 0;
        p->left = p->right = 0;
    }
    return p;
}
```

and call `alloc_node()` instead of `malloc()` to allocate a new node.

Comment: What is the purpose of assigning data to 0, if it is zero by default anyway?

Comment: As I said, "The item returned by malloc() is not guaranteed to be initialized to zeros (or any other particular value)".

Comment: Use the value `NULL`, indicating an empty pointer, not value `0` which is an integer.

Comment: @user3614293 unless you're using calloc, memory will not be automatically initialized for you

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns newly allocated data but does not zero fill (initialize) the allocated structure.
Therefore, if left and right are pointers, they point to a random, non-zero address. Consequently it appears is if you try to free data that you did not allocate.

A fix might look like this:

```
    ...
    tree->right = malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
    bzero(tree->right, sizeof(BinaryTree));
    add(data, tree->right);
    ...
```

Comment: Initializing data is not the same as allocating memory, you can `free` memory which you did not initialize (or touch in any way), e.g : http://ideone.com/2D4Dc3

Comment: OK clarified explanation.